# Using pandas index as dictionary key, fill dictionary with values based on matching keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a `test_df` organized like so:

```
[in]
# Use the arrays to create a dataframe
testing_df =pd.DataFrame(test_array,columns=['transaction_id','product_id'])

# Split the product_id's for the testing data
testing_df.set_index(['transaction_id'],inplace=True)

print(testing_df.head(n=5))

[out]
                     product_id
transaction_id                 
001                      (P01,)
002                  (P01, P02)
003             (P01, P02, P09)
004                  (P01, P03)
005             (P01, P03, P05)
```

I then performed some calculations on it and created a dictionary to store the results:

```
# Initialize a dictionary to store the matches
matches = {}

# Return the product combos values that are of the appropriate length and the strings match
for transaction_id,i in enumerate (testing_df['product_id']):
    recommendation = None
    recommended_count = 0

    for k, count in product_combos.items():
        k = list(k)
        if len(i)+1 == len(k) and count >= recommended_count:
            for product in i:
                if product in k: 
                    k.remove(product)
            if len(k) == 1:
                recommendation = k[0]
                recommended_count = count
    matches[transaction_id] = recommendation

print(matches)

[out]
{0: 'P09', 1: 'P09', 2: 'P06', 3: 'P09', 4: 'P09', 5: 'P09'}
```

The problem I have is that the keys of the `matches` dictionary should be `001,002,003,004,005` etc. - corresponding to the index of the `test_df` which is 001-100.

The second issue I have is that I would like to fill another dictionary (`recommendations`) with the keys being 001-100. I would like the fill the values from `matches` into this dict by matching the key-values.

Comment: Try casting the keys to a string first. If that doesn't work, do `str(key).rjust(3, '0')`

Comment: That doesnt work, when i change it to `k = list(str(k))` the whole dictionary comes back empty

Comment: What is `k`? I was assuming that was an integer ID.  I don't know what `product_combos` is. If you want to cast an entire index series as a string with the leading 3 0's you can do `df.index.astype(str).str.rjust(3, '0')`

Comment: `k` is the key value from the `product_combos` dict which I am comparing to the `product_id` column of the df....in the function, I would like to return the `test_df` index as the key value for `matches`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here.  First, the order of the variables you're asking for from `enumerate` is switched - the integer counter comes first:

```
for i, entry in enumerate(values):
    ...
```

That's why the keys in the `matches` dict appear as integers.

Second, you still need to access the `i`th element of `testing_df.index` to get the `transaction_id` you're looking for.  You can do this with the `i` from your (corrected) `enumerate()`:

```
# sample data
transaction_id = ["001","002","003","004","005"]
product_id = {"product_id":[("P01",), ("P01", "P02"), ("P01", "P02", "P09"),
                            ("P01", "P03"), ("P01", "P03", "P05")]}
testing_df = pd.DataFrame(product_id, index=transaction_id)
testing_df.index.name = "transaction_id"

print(testing_df)
                     product_id
transaction_id                 
001                      (P01,)
002                  (P01, P02)
003             (P01, P02, P09)
004                  (P01, P03)
005             (P01, P03, P05)

matches = {}

for i, entry in enumerate(testing_df.product_id):

    # ... some computation ...

    transaction_id = testing_df.index[i]
    recommendation = entry[0] # just as an example
    matches[transaction_id] = recommendation

print(matches)
{'001': 'P01', '002': 'P01', '003': 'P01', '004': 'P01', '005': 'P01'}
```

Comment: `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Recall that you had `i` in the wrong position.  Now, `i` is correctly representing the row index in your loop.  You'll need to update the rest of your code to reflect the correction.